# How to display selected checbox data jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have text box(for live search) and whenever i enter more than 3 characters then
result is showing (from database) via ajax response as checkboxes with name, I just want whenever user
select any checkbox so this checkbox should display in div so user can search multiple data and can see
selected checkboxes,How can i do this ?

Right now Here is my html code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <form action="/">
        <h1>Newsletter Form</h1>
        <p class="question">Newsletter Type?</p>
        <div class="question-answer">
          <label><input type="radio" value="Delas" name="DealType" /> Deals</label>
          <label><input type="radio" value="PremiumDeals" name="DealType" /> Premium Deals</label>
        </div>
        
        <div id="deals-section" style="display:none;">
        
        <p class="question">Add Merchant Name</p>
        <div class="question-answer">
          <input type="text" name="merchantname" id="merchantname" value="">
        </div>
        
        <div id="suggestions">
        <div id="suggestionslist">
        </div>
        </div>  
    
<img id="loading-image" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif" style="display:none;"/>   
        <table id="fees_table">
</table>
        <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-xs-3"></label>
                        <div class="col-xs-8">
                            <ul id="sparepartList" style="list-style-type: none; padding: 0;"></ul>
                        </div>
          </div>
        <div class="btn-block" id="send" >
          <button type="submit" href="/">Send</button>
        </div>
        
        </div>
      </form>
```

Here is my script which showing "MerchantName"(data from database) with "checkbox",i just want whenever we click on any
checkbox this "Merchant Data" should display in seprate div/belowcheckbox, How can i do this ?

```
<script>
$('#merchantname').keyup(function() {
 var merchantname = $(this).val();
 if(merchantname.length>= 3){
         $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
               url: "<?php echo base_url('Newsletter/GetMerchantName');?>",
               cache : false,
              data: {'merchantname': merchantname},
               dataType: "json",
               async: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
              $("#loading-image").show();
           },   
            success: function(response) {
                $('#sparepartList').empty();
                $.each(response, function(key,value) 
                {
                    let li = $('<li><input type="checkbox" name="merchantName[]" value="' + value.merchantName + '" />' +
                                '<input type="text" name="sparepart" value="' + value.merchantName + '" /></li>');
                        $('#sparepartList').append(li);
              });
                $("#loading-image").hide();
            },
            error: function(response) {
                 console.log(response);
                } 
    })
    return false;
 }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the checkbox value on checked with jquery.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
    var val = this.checked ? this.value : '';
    $('#showDiv').html(val);
});
```

Comment: Two suggestions: (1) Make the selector scoped so that it's triggered only for check boxes within the list (2) The checked values should be appended rather than display it directly within the loop. In the current code, `showDiv` will always display the last checked value.

Comment: @BukhariBaBa: not working, Actually i want to get id/show div on "Ajax response checkboxes " not in html checkboxes